# how to use specific functions in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

there are many functions in magento2 , but i dont know where should i use it , where it works and where it won't , as example in module-catalog/model/layer/filter/Price.php , there are many functions like apply function

as i know this is the function that return the interval price like this $150.00 - $199.99 (22)
now if i want to use it how? if we have a collection of product and i loop trought them like this

notice apply function is only example

```
foreach($productCollection as $product){

}
```

it won't work like this $product->apply();

or like this

$productCollection->apply()

i think the idea is clear now , and there are many functions like it

[image]

Comment: What exaclty is your questions? Its quite unclear.